# After converting a string to an array I get a wrong array length

Tags: javascript, regex, arrays

In my browser console.log (as a result from a socket.io answer from the server) I have this string that I need to transform in array:

```
'test.tif[0] TIFF 1962x2668+0+0 DirectClass 1-bit 12.8M 0.000u 0:01
 test.tif[1] TIFF 1952x2688+0+0 DirectClass 1-bit 12.8M 0.000u 0:01
 test.tif[2] TIFF 1650x2200+0+0 DirectClass 1-bit 12.8M 0.000u 0:01
 test.tif[3] TIFF 1654x2204+0+0 DirectClass 1-bit 12.8M 0.000u 0:01
 test.tif[4] TIFF 1654x2206+0+0 DirectClass 1-bit 12.8M 0.000u 0:01
 test.tif[5] TIFF 1654x2206+0+0 DirectClass 1-bit 12.8M 0.000u 0:01

                                                                    '
```

After `data.split(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm);`

The console.log show me this:

```
 test.tif[0] TIFF 1962x2668+0+0 DirectClass 1-bit 12.8M 0.000u 0:01,
,test.tif[1] TIFF 1952x2688+0+0 DirectClass 1-bit 12.8M 0.000u 0:01,
,test.tif[2] TIFF 1650x2200+0+0 DirectClass 1-bit 12.8M 0.000u 0:01,
,test.tif[3] TIFF 1654x2204+0+0 DirectClass 1-bit 12.8M 0.000u 0:01,
,test.tif[4] TIFF 1654x2206+0+0 DirectClass 1-bit 12.8M 0.000u 0:01,
,test.tif[5] TIFF 1654x2206+0+0 DirectClass 1-bit 12.8M 0.000u 0:01,
,
```

.......with an extra comma.

When I  do `data.length` I get a result of 99.
How is it possible? What would be the best solution to get the correct value?

Comment: There's an extra blank line at the end, from the looks of it.

Comment: When I take your string, trim it, and split it, I get a length (of the result array) of 11 (in Firefox). The length is 11 because there are six lines, and the result array will include the separators (5 of them). If you use the regex `/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/gm` instead, then you just get the contents and not the separators in the result array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. By using groups in JavaScript you cause the matched groups to be included as items in the split results.  So if you had a regex like `(,)` to split `A,B`, the result would be `[0] = 'A', [1] = ',', [2] = 'B'`.
2. You can use a look ahead to ensure that there is text after each element so you don't include any blank elements.

### Regex

```
(?:[\r\n]+\s*)+(?=\w)
```

### [REY](http://rey.gimenez.biz/s/zmk68n)

The above regex has the advantage of trimming any extra white space, which might be overkill in your case.  Also `[\r\n]+` might be considered my effective than `\r\n|\n|\r` in that it will capture multiple consecutive lines of breaks as well as the originally intended matches.

Comment: Instead of: `(?=\w)` I'd use: `(?=\S)`. The reason being that there may be a valid chunk following a line break that does not begin with a word char, e.g. a `"quoted string"` or perhaps an html entity `&amp;`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you've got an extra newline after your data, strip it out first.
Use `data = data.replace(/\s$/,"");` before `data.split(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm);`

Comment: I got rid of the blank line but I still have the extra comma and the data.length is again 99

Answer (score 0):

... 'cause there is a new line at the end of your input.

Can you trim first before split

```
data.trim().split(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm);
```

Comment: Note: Trim doesn't exist in older browsers, like IE 8.